# Load files from a folder using natural order

Tags: c#

in a folder, I have these files. the order on windows explorer is:

- input (1).jpg
- input (2).jpg
- input (101).jpg

This is the way I got the files from the folder:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(inputImage, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

But the order will be:

- input (1).jpg
- input (101).jpg
- input (2).jpg

Even I tried: `Array.Sort(files);`

But the order is the same, How can I load the files with this order:

- input (1).jpg
- input (2).jpg
- input (101).jpg

Comment: Natural sorting http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'll try something like this:

```
        var files = from file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
        .Where(f => f.Extension == ".jpg")
                    orderby ExtractNumber(file.Name) ascending
                    select file.FullName;
        return files.ToList<string>();
```

Here we extract the file number -between the ( and )-.

```
private static object ExtractNumber(string p)
{
    int lenght = p.IndexOf(')') - p.IndexOf('(');
    return int.Parse(p.Substring(p.IndexOf('('), lenght - 1)); 
}
```

I'm pretty sure there must be an efficient way to do this, but just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to implement your own comparison to compare two strings in a way which "realizes" that they contain embedded non-zero-padded numbers. Explorer contains this logic already, and (as per the comment) this is exposed in `StrCmpLogicalW` which you could call with [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.strcmplogicalw) in a custom `Comparer<string>` implementation which you could pass to a sorting method.

If you know everything else about the name (i.e. the pattern) then it's easy to strip out the fixed parts for the comparison - but `StrCmpLogicalW` will give you a nice general implementation.

Of course if you're in control of whatever's creating the files, a simpler approach is to zero-pad the filenames to some reasonable number of digits, e.g. 5 or 6.

Comment: Not sure if its what explorer uses but Win32's StrCmpLogicalW would give the desired order

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Array.Sort(files) is, by default, sorting file names as text, not as numbers.  Try parsing the numbers and then sorting by those.

Answer (score 2):

If you load the files in a simple way:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles ("folder");
```

and assuming that there is always a number in parentheses you can use a function:

```
Array.Sort (files, compareFilesWithBrackets);
```

with a comparison function:

```
public static int compareFilesWithBrackets (string arg1, string arg2)
{
        string filename1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName (arg1); //extract filename from the path of the first file
        string filename2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName (arg2); // extract second file filename
        Match m = Regex.Match (filename1, "\\(([0-9]+)\\)"); // check if there is (number) for file 1
        int file1 = 0; // if no number leave 0
        if (m.Success) { // else if success parse the number from brackets
            file1 = int.Parse (m.Groups [1].Value); 
        }
        m = Regex.Match (filename2, "\\(([0-9]+)\\)");
        int file2 = 0;
        if (m.Success) {
            file2 = int.Parse (m.Groups [1].Value); 
        }
        return file1 - file2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd create a dictionary object and store the first value as the original filename, and the 2nd as a custom filename that you will need to massage.

So, for instance, the dictionary object would look something like this:

```
input (1).jpg    |  input (001).jpg
input (2).jpg    |  input (002).jpg
input (101).jpg  |  input (101).jpg
```

Then you can sort on the 2nd field, but pull the filename from the first field in the dictionary object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OrderBy extension, more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

It's a simple lambda expression the t=> t part. You can do some manipulation before it gets sorted if need be.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(inputImage, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderBy(t => t);
```

If you wanted to sort only on the number, you could some some clever string substitution like

```
.OrderBy(t => t.Replace("input", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")","").Trim());
```

Comment: I tried this within Replace(".jpg", "") but it does not work :p

Comment: Ah, should have cast it to an int, eg .OrderBy(t => int.Parse(t.Replace("input", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")","").Trim()));

Comment: Really, you could have just used a regular expression to grab the number, and ordered it on that.

Answer (score 1):

This [CustomSort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052176/932418) can help

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
   "input (1).jpg","input (101).jpg", "input (11).jpg", "input (2).jpg"
};

var sortedList = list.CustomSort().ToList();
```

Output will be:

```
input (1).jpg
input (2).jpg
input (11).jpg
input (101).jpg
```

I'll copy the code here

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> CustomSort(this IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        int maxLen = list.Select(s => s.Length).Max();

        return list.Select(s => new
        {
            OrgStr = s,
            SortStr = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+)|(\D+)", m => m.Value.PadLeft(maxLen, char.IsDigit(m.Value[0]) ? ' ' : '\xffff'))
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortStr)
        .Select(x => x.OrgStr);
    }
}
```