# Linq ordering by number on file name

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

I'm trying to order a set of files base on its file name. Input is a directory with files like:

```
f0.vesperdp
f1.vesperdp
f2.vesperdp
....
f9.vesperdp
f10.vesperdp
f11.vesperdp
f12.vesperdp
```

I've built this LINQ query to sort them:

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = from file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()

    .Where(f => f.Extension == PAGE_FILE_EXTENSION)
                orderby file.Name.Substring(1, file.Name.Length - 1) ascending
                select file.FullName;

    return files.ToArray<string>();
}
```

But they are returning like

```
f0.vesperdp
f1.vesperdp
f10.vesperdp
....
f19.vesperdp
f2.vesperdp
f20.vesperdp
f21.vesperdp
```

I need them to be sorted using natural order (from 0 to n as `f0,f1,f2...,f9,f10,f11`) how can fix my orderby filter to match this? Or if there's other way, how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: See this [custom sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052176/932418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naspinski's correct in theory, but here's the solution in code.

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = from file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()

    .Where(f => f.Extension == PAGE_FILE_EXTENSION)
                orderby int.Parse(file.Name.Substring(1, file.Name.IndexOf('.')-1)) ascending
                select file.FullName;

    return files.ToArray<string>();
}
```

The order-by clause basically changes to pull everything between the leading 'f' and the first dot, which from your examples will be a number string, which is then parsed into an integer number and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It is ordering the string correctly, you are going to have to pull *just* the number out, convert to Integer, then order. This is untested, but you get the idea:

```
public int GetInt(string filename)
{
    int idx = file.Name.IndexOf(".");
    if(idx < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return Convert.ToInt32(filename.SubString(1, file.Name.Length - (idx - 1)));
}
```

Then your orderby part:

```
.Where(f => f.Extension == PAGE_FILE_EXTENSION)
    orderby GetInt(file.Name) ascending
    select file.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the `int` value out of the name and `orderby` using that value:

```
.Where(f => f.Extension == PAGE_FILE_EXTENSION)
        orderby int.Parse(file.Name.Substring(1, file.Name.Length -
                          file.Extension.Length-1)) ascending
        select file.FullName;
```

Comment: This will throw an exception. You need to stop your parsing at the period.

Comment: Won't work; file.Name includes the extension, so the substring being pulled from `f0.vesperdp` would be `0.vesperdp` which is non-numeric.