# Create video from a list of images

Tags: c#, image, cmd, vlc

I want to save a list of images into one video using simple technique like `vlc` with the `cmd`.
In my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196381/cant-sort-files-from-folder-in-string-array), I have images in `Date modify` order, and with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) i can execute any command in the `cmd`, so what command should I use to save these images to one video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <imagefile> -vcodec mpeg4 out_movie.avi
```

It would help to name the images incrementally so you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i image_%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 out_movie.avi
```

You can specify two frame rates, the input and the output rate:

- The input rate is the rate according to which the images are read. It is specified by setting `-r` **before** `-i`. The default value for reading input is `25` which will be set if no -r is specified.
- The output rate is the frame rate of the video stream that is generated. It is specified by seting `-r` **after** `-i`, or by using the fps filter. If you want the input and output frame rates to be the same, then just declare an input -r and the output will inherit the same value.

If you want to upgrade your setup further, here is an article on how to create [a simple c# Wrapper for ffmpeg](http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/).

Also, if you are on Linux, you can find a nice tutorial here:
http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html