# String array sorting trouble

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm getting all the files in a folder and putting them into a string array. The problem I'm having is the string array will not sort right with the pages that have a number larger than 9. What would be the easiest way to get the string array to sort the right way? As you can see the very first pdf is A10C and it should show up under A9C, but it's showing up first. Same thing is happening with B10C:

```
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A10C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A1C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A2C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A3C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A4C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A5C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A6C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A7C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A8C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-A9C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B10C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B1C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B2C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B3C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B4B.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B5C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B6C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B7C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B8C.pdf
\\server\archives\PAPER\20140818\NJ-140818-B9C.pdf
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What you want is a [Natural Sort](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/), where numbers are treated as numbers instead of characters.

Comment: Natural sort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: why not just put them into a List<String> and use the internal sorting that comes along with a List<T> show more effort there are tons of examples on line [Array.Sort](http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/)

Comment: Answers to [Natural sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) cover pretty much all ways to extract number to compare to - make sure to check all answers if you think your problem is completely different. Feel free to update your post to show how your one is different and comment/flag to reopen.

Comment: @DJKRAZE The built-in sort will not give the results that the OP wants.

Comment: user1800738, You can also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052176/932418)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of regex and linq

```
var sorted = strs
    .OrderBy(s => DateTime.ParseExact(Regex.Match(s, @"PAPER\\(\d+)\\").Groups[1].Value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ThenBy(s => Regex.Match(s, @"(\w)\d+\w.pdf").Groups[1].Value)
    .ThenBy(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\w(\d+)\w.pdf").Groups[1].Value))
    .ThenBy(s => Regex.Match(s, @"\w\d+(\w).pdf").Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks guys natural sort was exactly what I was looking for, this code works perfectly. http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting