# foreach file in folder (in numeric order)

Tags: c#, foreach

This isn't really a big problem because I know I can just use a for loop but basically I have a folder with 20 images all named "Image1", "Image2", etc...

Then I wanted to add them as an attachment to an email in order using this code...

```
foreach (var Image in ImageFilePaths)
{
    Message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Image));
    Console.WriteLine(Image);
}
```

pretty simple, it adds them all but in the order of 1, 10-19, 2, 20, 3-9. I get why as its kind of going from smallest to biggest in a weird way, but I wanted straight up 1-20. I'm just looking for a quick fix as I know if it comes to it I can just use:

```
int imagecounter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i >= 20; i++)
{
    //add image path + imagecounter + jpg;
    imagecounter++
}
```

Comment: Do you also generate the filenames or does another program do that?

Comment: Pull the number from the filename and sort by that value.

Comment: it also generates the filenames, i can change it to something that will work if u have something in mind

Comment: then they will all be called "Image" allan?

Comment: Use the CustomSort you can found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052095/how-can-i-sort-a-string-of-text-followed-by-a-number-using-linq/11052176#11052176

Comment: Could be done also without using a CustomSort with a rather complicated Linq and Regex expression

Comment: ImageFilePaths.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(6)) may work for you (if the file prefix is 'Image' for all files). You can use System.IO.Path to get the file name.